22.04 held back updates for update-manager over 123 days
This is a specific question about a held back package group.
The update-manager group includes update-manager-core and python3-update-manager.
It is in the SRU list of phased updates for 123 days with 0% distributed.
It would be nice if the SRU list included additional information but it doesn't so here we are.  Yes, it includes errors but those aren't available to the general public.
What is happening with this specific update?

I think this packages are for testing in proposed.

i found this maybe it i usefull for you. https://ubuntu-archive-team.ubuntu.com/proposed-migration/jammy/update_excuses.html#update-manager

It still doesn't explain why or the plan to move forward
